# string.IsNullOrEmpty() method not handling session variables properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, vwdexpress, isnullorempty

Using C#, asp.net in VWD 2010.

I have a session variable assigned manually in site.master (for testing purposes).  I set the value as:  Session["userid"] = (int) number

In my web page, I have the following code:

```
        litmsg.Text = "userid = " + Session["userid"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["userid"] as string))
        {
            Session["errmsg"] = "No user ID is specified";
            litmsg.Text = litmsg.Text + "   inside loop";
          //  Response.Redirect("/PageError.aspx");
        }
        return;
```

During execution, the value in litmsg.Text is the correct user id, which tells me that Session["userid"] must have a value.  However, if it has a value, then the string.IsNullOrEmpty() should return false, meaning the body should not be executed, and I should not see the phrase "inside loop."

The string.IsNullOrEmpty() also seems to fail in my PageError page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string strErrMess = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["errmess"] as string) ? 
                   "Unspecificed error message" :
                    Session["errmess"].ToString();

            errmess.Text = strErrMess;
        }
}
```

In this case, it reports an unspecified message, even when I have set a value for Session["errmess"].

The thing is I use this idiom in other contexts and it seems to work - it's only when I apply it to the Session variable I have a problem.  Is there something I'm missing

I have found references to a bug in PREVIOUS versions of the function when used with session variables, but those references indicate the bug has been fixed in current versions.  For example, here: [C# String.IsNullOrEmpty: good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690974/c-sharp-string-isnullorempty-good-or-bad)

I like this idiom, as I'm already using it in other places.  Is there a better way of doing this? One that works?  Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You are not calling `ToString()` before checking if it is a string or not.  You assigned it with an `int` value so of course it's not a string.

Comment: I thought it might fail the ToString() if the value was null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
string strErrMess = (Session["errmess"] == null)
    ? "Unspecificed error message" 
    : Session["errmess"].ToString();
```

You are casting it as a string before testing if it's null, so it's throwing the error.

Comment: In my case, I reverse the sense to ==null || == "", but that works!
Thanks!

Comment: sure thing.  Always make sure you perform the null check first, as the right side won't be evaluated if that fails (and thus won't throw an exception)

Answer (score 1):

If you cast an `int` to type `string`, it will result in a null reference, since it cannot be cast to that type. Therefore, the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method will return true.